# Can I identify $X/A$ with the one-point compactification of $X-A$, where $X\supset A$ is a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Intuitively, $A$ collapses to a single point which may represent the infinity point of the one point compactification of $X-A$. Definitely, we should assume $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff.

For example, if $X=S^n$ and $A={pt}$, a single point, then $X/A \cong X = S^n$ while $X-A \cong \mathbb R^n$, whose one point compactification is exactly $S^n$.

However, I am not sure if this is right for general topological spaces. And, I am trying to find out the exact conditions to guarantee this identification. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What if your $X$ isn't already compact?

Comment: Fact is that the conditions are different: in the one-point compactification of $Y$, a set $U\ni\infty$ is open if and only if $U\cap Y$ is the complement of a compact subset of $Y$. Viceversa, if we call $s=\pi(A)\in X/A$, a set $U\ni s$ is open if and only if it is in the form $\pi(V)$ for some open set $V\supseteq A$. So it is clear that, if we call $S=(X-A)\cup\{P\}$, call $\tau_1$ the topology makes it into the one-point compactification of $(X-A)$ and $\tau_2$ the topology that makes it into $X/A$, $\tau_1$ will naturally be coarser that $\tau_2$, and often it will be strictly coarser.

Comment: For instance, if $A$ is open, than $\pi(A)$ is an open point, while typically $\infty$ is not open.

Comment: Just spitballing here: what if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\{a,b\}$ with $a\neq b$? I don't think $X/A$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $X- A$.

Answer (score 4):

*(Partial answer)*

**Edit:** Corrected earlier omission: it is also necessary that $A$ be closed.

As G. Sassatelli points out, the definition of an open set in $X / A$ and in the compactification of $(X \setminus A)$ are different. A partial answer to your question is to determine under what conditions the *canonical bijection* between $X / A$ and the compactifiation of $(X \setminus A)$ is a homeomorphism.

First we consider the topology restricted to $(X \setminus A)$. $X \setminus A$ is open in the one-point compactification of the space $X \setminus A$, so it must also be open in $X / A$. It follows then immediately that **$\boldsymbol{A}$ must be closed**.
This guarantees that the topology on $X \setminus A$ has the same open sets as in $X$, so that open sets in $X \setminus A$ are the same as in the original topology of $X$ in both spaces.

From here, the additional condition we want is that the open sets coincide for sets containing the extra point: for any set $V \subseteq (X \setminus A)$, $V \cup \{[A]\}$ is open in $X/A$ if and only if $V \cup \{\infty\}$ is open in the compactification of $(X \setminus A)$. Unpacking these definitions, we want
$$
V \cup A \text{ is open} \iff X \setminus (V \cup A) \text{ is compact}
$$
The $\Longleftarrow$ is true if $X$ is Hausdorff: if $X \setminus (V \cup A)$ is compact, then it is closed, so its complement $V \cup A$ is open.

The $\Longrightarrow$ direction says: the complement of an open set containing $A$ is compact. Or in other words, a closed set disjoint from $A$ must be compact.

**In summary:**

- If $X$ is Hausdorff, then a necessary and sufficient condition is that (i) $A$ is closed, and (ii) every closed set disjoint from $A$ is compact. (Perhaps others can reduce this condition further to something else well-known.)
- In particular, **if $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $A$ is closed,** then the two are always equivalent. This covers the case you discussed, of $S^n$.